# Regular Expression: adding bookmark html tags depending on various range of numbers

Tags: html, regex, numbers, notepad++, replace

I have some html pages with numbers of verses like:

```
verses 2-5
verses 11-15
verses 21-23
```

I need to add for each number a code before the word "verses"
to be

```
<a name="2"></a><a name="3"></a><a name="4"></a><a name="5"></a>verses 2-5
```

etc.

So it takes the range of the numbers given, and before the beginning it adds:

```
<a name=""></a>
```

for each number in the range..

I use notepad++ to search and replace.

Comment: Regex can't do this. You'll have to write a script.

Comment: If the verse ranges are demarcated how about DOM manipulation with JS based on content. That way you don't "hard code" bookmarks but generate them on the fly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to need a script to do this. I whipped up a simple Ruby script to do it. Used it on your sample text, got your output. Just download Ruby, paste this into a file in the directory of that text, and replace the `verses.txt` line with whatever your file name is. Then run it from the command line like: `ruby ./script.rb`

```
d = File.read('./verses.txt')
c = d[0..d.length]
c.scan(/(verses\s+\d+-\d+)/) do |n|
  n.each do |a|
    a.scan(/(\d+-\d+)/) do |nums|
      z = nums.to_s.split(/-/)
      st=''
      in1 = z[0].gsub(/\["/, '').to_i
      in2 = z[1].chomp("\"]").to_i
      (in1..in2).each do |index|
        st += "<a name=\"#{index}\"></a>"
      end
      b = st + a;
      d.gsub!(a, b)
    end
  end
end
puts d
f = File.new('verses2.txt', "w")
f.write(d)
```

Per your request, here is a modification that will overwrite the opened file and run on all files in a directory. For ease, I won't do directory entry, so place the script in the directory of all the files to run it. Here goes:

```
Dir.entries('.').each do |entry|
    entry.scan(/.*.html/) do
        |fn|
        d = File.read('./' + fn.to_s)
        c = d[0..d.length]
        c.scan(/(verses\s+\d+-\d+)/) do |n|
          n.each do |a|
            a.scan(/(\d+-\d+)/) do |nums|
              z = nums.to_s.split(/-/)
              st=''
              in1 = z[0].gsub(/\["/, '').to_i
              in2 = z[1].chomp("\"]").to_i
              (in1..in2).each do |index|
                st += "<a name=\"#{index}\"></a>"
              end
              b = st + a;
              d.gsub!(a, b)
            end
          end
        end
        puts d
        f = File.new('./' + fn.to_s, "w")
        f.write(d)
    end
end
```

I'll think about how to do the arabic encodings. This will run on all text files, if they have different extensions or have a similar name, let me know and I'll update the script.

This should fully work, just tested it. Let me know if there are issues.

Comment: it works great..  thanks..  however when I try it with Arabic text, the encoding gets garbled..  how can it be fixed? and how can I make the edits in the same files, and for bulk files in a directory?  (I don't want to enter the names of hundreds of files)..  thanks

Comment: Not sure how to fix the encoding... shit. I'll edit the answer to show you how to overwrite the file you're reading and loop through a directory. Is there a pattern of all the files in the directory?

Comment: what about making the code edits directly in the same input files and not create a new file?  and to edit *.html of the files in that directory without giving it any filenames?

Comment: I was gonna tell you how to do that in the comments, but it got to long. I updated my post with a new script, try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it for 2-digit verses 10 to 99 like this:

```
Search: verses (\d)(\d)-
Replace: <a name="$1">verses $1$2-</a>
```

For 3+ digit numbers, add another group for the extra digit(s) and treat similarly.

This extra complication is required because notepad++ doesn't support look-aheads AFAIK.

Comment: the output shows as: <a name="2">verses 25-</a> and not <a name="2"></a><a name="3"></a><a name="4"></a><a name="5"></a>verses 2-5